# Visual studio code menu bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]
do any one have a fix to that?
the menu bar is hidden behind the X/FULL SCREEN/MINIMIZE buttons

I tried to look it up and ask people but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

please click in keyboard: **Ctrl+Alt+X** combination

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: open toolbox menu

Comment: id dosent do anything

Comment: are you using Visual Studio Code? question title in "Visual Studio"

Comment: yes visual studio code

Comment: but title Visual Studio. title change please

Comment: done..sorry im new here